# Fragment OnResume() after OnPause()

Tags: android, android-fragments, onresume, onpause

I have an application, part of which is a fragment in which the camera takes a pic, when the picture is taken another fragment is loaded to display the image.  The user then has the choice to retake the pic if not happy.  This should go back to the previous fragment (camera) and it does as the overlay is displayed, however the image previously taken is still displayed.

EDIT****
I debugged through it and when the image is taken and the next fragment is loaded, the onpause() isn't called, so, when the user clicks retake, the onresume isnt called which reinstantiates my camera. I know there have been similar questions here but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem.****EDIT

It should be said that I am integrating with someone elses work here and that is causing confusion.  Here are the two methods for going to next fragment and going to previous fragment

**NEXT**

```
public void gotoNextFragment(String nextTag, Fragment nextFragment){

    FragmentManager  fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.enter_slide_in, R.animator.enter_slide_out);

    boolean newlyCreated = false;
    if(nextFragment == null){
        nextFragment = Fragment.instantiate(this, nextTag);
        newlyCreated = true;
    }

    //hide current fragment
    ft.hide(fm.findFragmentByTag(Misc.currentContentFragmentTag));

    if(newlyCreated){
        ft.add(R.id.content_frame, nextFragment, nextTag);
    }
    else{
        ft.show(nextFragment);
    }
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    Misc.currentContentFragmentTag = nextTag;

}
```

**PREVIOUS**

```
public void gobackToPreviousFragment(String preFragmentTag,Fragment f){

    FragmentManager  fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.close_slide_in,R.animator.close_slide_out);

    ft.show(f);
    ft.remove(fm.findFragmentByTag(Misc.currentContentFragmentTag));                    
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    Misc.currentContentFragmentTag = preFragmentTag;

}
```

If anyone would have any insight as to what I need to do to ensure onResume() is called I'd appreciate it...

**EDIT
The image preview that is still displayed is that of the standard camera image preview, not from the fragment for previewing**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `hide()` `show()` fragments you don't get a call to `onResume()`. Then you only get a call the first time the fragment is created.

Comment: ok, so if I hide, I don't get onPause called either?  Is there a way around this?  or do you have to replace the fragment in order for onPause() and in turn onResume() to be called?

Comment: why didn't I think of that...looking at it for too long!!  so on hide just call onPause and same for show..(onResume)?

Comment: @DJ-DOO No not quite. Whatever you want to happen in onPause() I'd move out to a new method and call that. Same goes for onResume().

Comment: ahh thx, that is good to know. thought that hide/show is connected to the lifecycle.

Comment: @bofredo I kinda did too, but I guess that's an advantage as well. You can have instant response from fragments which are hidden. You don't need to create everything in order to show them again.

Answer (score 1):

the onResume()-method is always called before the fragment is running. check the lifecycle-diagram --> http://docs.xamarin.com/static/guides/android/platform_features/fragments/part_1_-_creating_a_fragment/Images/fragment_lifecycle.png

Comment: I understand that, I've debugged through my code and I've studied that.  However, should the onResume() not also be called when a fragment or activity is reactivated after an onPause is called?

Comment: yes it should. try to override the onResume()-method and add some Log.i or Toast in it, to test if it really gets called when it should be. At least you you will get new useful info on your problem!

Comment: it's not though, I know this because I had break points in the onresume, now I've added toast to be sure and I know for sure it's not, but I still don't know why